# iOS - How can I insert custom audio codec while playing Live stream

Tags: ios, swift, audio, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am using AVPlayer to play live stream. Everything was working fine, but from iOS 16.4 live stream is not working when camera is muted. When I checked m3u8 file then I found that audio codec is missing. Due to this live stream is not playing.

How can I solve this issue?
Can I inject custom audio codec on iOS side?
Can I override m3u8?